# "Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies" is gone when internet is connected

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I recently updated to Android Studio version 3.6. When I started a new project the gradle build took some time and I got this error **Check your module class-path for missing or conflicting dependencies**.
I just randomly turned my internet connection to ON and the error was gone.
Can someone tell me why this would have happened ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> missing or conflicting dependencies

The formar should have happened when your internet connection was off-line. Because Gradle couldn't reach the library, it thought that was missing.